# List component alternative to list.js that would support drag n drop

Tags: jquery-ui, javascript, listjs, web-control

Javve's List.js is nice component but there are difficulties to drop items into -  you can't just add item with your html, you should add it through List API using json class and then component will create item for you using its template (loosing all attributes values since it is impossible using this template set up attributes)....

Could you recommend any other list component (with filter and paging to which would be easy to drop items)?

P.S If you know how to drop into list.js - please tell me the secret.
P.P.S It is possible to drug from list.js (so if you do not need to return item to list this component works well)